Azure Functions - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0
I'm attempting to create an Azure Function with a Service Bus Trigger. It builds fine locally however when I come to trying to run it, I receive this error:
[2024-11-28T12:47:02.953Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '2fe67e9d-b8ad-4ee6-9603-18ba874fbe69'.
[2024-11-28T12:47:02.953Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error building configuration in an external startup class. TransactionEventsProcessor: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have the following nuget packages installed:
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.11.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="6.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.14.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />

If I also install Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, I get the same error message. Any suggestions on how to resolve this error?
Startup.cs class:
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageMapper, MessageMapper>();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
#if DEBUG
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true);
#else
    AzureAppConfig.Extensions.DependencyInjectionExtensions
        .AddAzureAppConfig(builder.ConfigurationBuilder)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
#endif
        base.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder);
    }
}

Function code:
public class IntegrationFunction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The message mapper
    /// </summary>
    private IMessageMapper messageMapper;

    /// <summary>
    /// Polling integration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message</param>
    /// <param name="logger">The logger.</param>
    /// <param name="messageActions">The message actions</param>
    /// <param name="queuedMessageClient">The mainframe queued message client</param>
    /// <param name="messageMapper">The message mapper</param>
    [FunctionName("IntegrationFunction")]
    [return: ServiceBus("%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ProcessorUpdateQueue%", Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
    public async Task<ServiceBusMessage> Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(
            "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic%",
            "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:TransactionEventsTopicSubscription%",
            Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ILogger logger,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions,
        IMainframeQueuedMessageClient queuedMessageClient,
        IMessageMapper messageMapper,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        try
        {
            var retailTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetailTransaction>(message.Body.ToString(), JsonSerialisationUtils.SerialiserSettings);
            if (retailTransaction == null)
                throw new TransactionDeserialisationException();

            if (retailTransaction.PollingEvents == null)
                return retailTransaction.GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.Completed);

            if (configuration?[Constants.DisableSendToMainframe] == null || configuration[Constants.DisableSendToMainframe].ToLowerInvariant().Equals("false"))
            {
                logger.LogWarning($"Transaction event messages for '{retailTransaction.TransactionNumber}' will not be sent due to app configuration {Constants.DisableSendToMainframe} being enabled" );
                return retailTransaction.GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.Completed);
            }

            return retailTransaction.GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.Completed);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ((RetailTransaction)null).GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.CompletedWithError, errorMessage: ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


Please share your function code

@IkhtesamAfrin added

Are you using .NET 6 or .NET 8?

I'm using .NET 8

I am using the same code alike you with few modification in it.
I have below codes in the mentioned files in .NET8 in-process Service Bus topic triggered function.
Function code :-
public class IntegrationFunction
{
    private readonly IMessageMapper _messageMapper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public IntegrationFunction(IMessageMapper messageMapper, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _messageMapper = messageMapper;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [FunctionName("IntegrationFunction")]

    [return: ServiceBus("%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ProcessorUpdateQueue%", Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
    public async Task<ServiceBusMessage> Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(
        "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:ReceiveTopic%",
        "%Transactions:SB:Transactions:TransactionEventsTopicSubscription%",
        Connection = "Transactions:SB:Transactions")]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
    ILogger logger,
    ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
    {
        try
        {
            var retailTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetailTransaction>(message.Body.ToString(), JsonSerialisationUtils.SerialiserSettings);
            if (retailTransaction == null)
                throw new TransactionDeserialisationException();

            if (retailTransaction.PollingEvents == null)
                return retailTransaction.GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.Completed);

            if (_configuration?[Constants.DisableSendToMainframe] == null || _configuration[Constants.DisableSendToMainframe].ToLowerInvariant().Equals("false"))
            {
                logger.LogWarning($"Transaction event messages for '{retailTransaction.TransactionNumber}' will not be sent due to app configuration {Constants.DisableSendToMainframe} being enabled");
                return retailTransaction.GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.Completed);
            }

            return retailTransaction.GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.Completed);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ((RetailTransaction)null).GetServiceBusMessage(CompletionResults.CompletedWithError, errorMessage: ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

Startup :-
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(_79233974.Startup))]

namespace _79233974
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageMapper, MessageMapper>();
        }

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        }
    }
}

.csproj :-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>_79233974</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

By having the above given codes, I am able to execute the function successfully in local.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6518 Commit hash: N/A +74ed9095fdd6c5326276aae6b8a7d41ccbdeb6aa (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.35.4.23179

[2024-12-02T05:30:22.442Z] Found C:\Users\****\79233974\79233974.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        IntegrationFunction: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-12-02T05:30:30.548Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-12-02T05:30:34.599Z] Executing 'IntegrationFunction' (Reason='(null)', Id=cb10e66e-0663-465b-a238-4d2628bb9688)
[2024-12-02T05:30:34.604Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 43a71be732f942baa3983e30f37edcb6, SequenceNumber: 2, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-12-02T05:30:34.1790000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-12-02T05:31:34.1950000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-12-02T05:30:34.646Z] Transaction event messages for '12345' will not be sent due to app configuration DisableSendToMainframe being enabled
[2024-12-02T05:30:35.799Z] Executed 'IntegrationFunction' (Succeeded, Id=cb10e66e-0663-465b-a238-4d2628bb9688, Duration=1326ms)


